# Loop of html using javascript

Tags: javascript

i am new on using of JavaScript on looping of html. I have this code below that i am working at. In this problem of mine i have `2` loop the main and the card-body loop. As you can see in the code First I need to loop the main to create a `card` and then at the body i need also to loop it because of the data content. I have also working code below but as you can see at the card-body its not looping anymore but static data that I inputted.

**Problem**

```
for (var i = 0; i < dataLength; i++) {
          var docsLength = data.data[i].resultData;
          var title = data.data[i].resultData[i].Type.Description;
          var card = '<div class="card"> <div class="card-header bg-success"><h3 class="card-title">' + title + ' </h3 ></div> <div class="card-body">'; for (var a = 0; a < 2; a++) { "a" } ' </div>' +
                '</div >';
           $("#card_documents > .card-body").append(card);
      }
```

**Working**

```
 for (var i = 0; i < dataLength; i++) {
                var docsLength = data.data[i].resultData;
                var title = data.data[i].resultData[i].Type.Description;
                var card = '<div class="card"> <div class="card-header bg-success"><h3 class="card-title">' + title + ' </h3 ></div> <div class="card-body">' +
                    "asdasdasdasd" +
                    '</div > ' +
                    '</div >';
                $("#card_documents > .card-body").append(card);
            }
```

Is my syntax wrong?. Please help. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your syntax is wrong. Specifically the way you're trying to use the for loop.

I would suggest building up the string in a variable.
Here is a stripped down version of how you might achieve that.

```
var card = '<div class="card">';
for (var a = 0; a < 2; a++) { 
    card += "a";
}
card += '</div>';
$("#card_documents > .card-body").append(card);
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I was doing it wrong from the start. I just need to append first the card and loop the card-body again.

Answer (score 2):

You can replace `for (var a = 0; a < 2; a++) { "a" }` with `"a".repeat(2)`.

[More info about `repeat()` here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/repeat)